# How to write this as one matrix?

Tags: matrices

I have a rather easy question, but I do not come along.

Let $Y$ be a $(n\times 1)$-matrix, $A$ a $(n\times n)$-matrix and $B$ a $(k\times n)$-matrix.

Consider $X=(AY,BY)$.

How can I write $X$ in the form "matrix" $\cdot$ $Y$?

Comment: What is the notation $(\cdot, \cdot)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let ${}^T$ denote the transpose of a matrix.  Assuming all entries are real, we have two options:
$$
(AY,BY) = (BY)^T AY = Y^T B^T A Y = (Y^TB^T A)Y
$$
Or
$$
(AY,BY) = (AY)^T BY = Y^TA^T B Y = (Y^TA^T B) Y
$$
So, you can select your "matrix" to be either $Y^TB^T A$ or $Y^TA^T B$.